# Prove that if $0<x\le y$ then $1/y \le 1/x$ using ordered field axioms

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, ordered-fields

Suppose that $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

Then, either $x = y$ or $x \leq y$.

If $x = y$, then $x^{-1} = y^{-1}$.

If $x < y$, then via proof by contradiction let's suppose $x < y$ implies $x^{-1} < y^{-1}$.

$$(x)(x^{-1})<(x)(y^{-1})$$
and hence
$$1<(x)y^{-1}$$
implies 
$$y<x$$

How should I take it further?

Comment: $0\lt x\leq y\implies y\geq x~,~x,y\gt 0\implies \dfrac{1}{y}\leq \dfrac{1}{x}$ Isn't this enough?

Comment: Note that **it works** even if $x,y$ **aren't** bounded below by $0$.

Comment: I don't understand,

Comment: It uses the fact that if you keep the numerator of a fraction constant, then the fraction with the largest denominator has the smallest value.

Comment: That I know but I need to prove it using axioms.

Comment: Then, you should _mention_ that in your question.

Comment: How would you prove it using axioms?

Comment: @user, I think you already proved it since $y\lt x$ is false by virtue of initial conditions. Hence your assumption that $x\lt y\implies x^{-1}\lt y^{-1}$ is false. By trichotomy principle and the fact that equality (for the proposed inequality) holds iff $x=y$, we have the obvious result that $x\lt y\implies x^{-1}\gt y^{-1}$. Reversing the inequality and combining the equality case gives you your required result.

Comment: Alright I think I understood.
We assume by contradiction that $x < y$ implies $ x^{-1)<y^{-1}$
but 
$x(x^{-1}) < x(y^{-1})$
therefore by transposition,
$y<x$
But this results in a contradiction to the original premise that x<y.
And so the conclusion that $x^{-1}<y^{-1}$ must be false

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $0 < x \leq y$. Then by the properties of inequalities, and the fact that $x^{-1}, y^{-1}$ exist in said field, $0< \frac{x}{y} \leq 1$. Further, $ 0 < \frac{1}{y} \leq \frac{1}{x} $.

To elaborate further, we were able to say that $x^{-1}*0=0$ and $y^{-1}*0=$ since we are in a field.

Comment: I think, and the comments agree that you may have over thought this one.